# How to customise the Nginx proxy_cache_key

Tags: nginx

If I make a request to:

```
example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

the variables:

```
$host = example.com
$request_uri = /?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

If I set my proxy_cache_key to:

```
proxy_cache_key    "$host$request_uri";
```

My cache will be keyed on:

```
example.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

I want my cache to key on the host name combined with only a portion of the request_uri:

```
example.com/?a=1
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

If you know which exact parameters you want to keep, you could set your key such as follows:

```
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$host$uri?a=$args_a&b=$args_b";
```